# How to get the exposed soap endpoints

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

I have a problem with a Soap enpoint, either it is not exposed, or it is exposed under a different name.
Other endpoints that I am working with, are found, but on the new one I get:

```
 org.springframework.ws.NoEndpointFoundException: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage mySoapEndpointRequest]
```

How can I get the exposed endpoints from Spring integration test? - to see if the endpoint is exposed or not, or it is exposed under a different name - maybe a typo or something.

On other endpoints the service it works and I don't see any difference.

Here is my integration test:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = {WebServiceConfigTest.class}, properties = {"application.address=http://hostname:port/context"})
 public class MySoapEndpointWebServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;



@Before
@Autowired
public void init() {
    mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void shouldSearch() throws JAXBException {
    //given
    String givenSearchStr = "cfhfghfg";
    Source requestPayload = buildRequestPayload(buildMockRequest(givenSearchStr)); // here the MySoapEndpointRequest object is serialized
    Source expectedResponsePayload = buildTestResponsePayload(buildMockSearchResponse(givenSearchStr ));
    //when
    mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload))
            //then
            .andExpect(noFault())
            .andExpect(payload(expectedResponsePayload));
}
```

The Webservice enpoint looks like this:

```
@Endpoint
public class MySoapEndpointWebService {

 public MySoapEndpointWebService (){}

 @PayloadRoot(namespace = SoapConstants.MY_SOAP_NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "mySoapEndpointRequest")
 @ResponsePayload
 public MySoapEndpointResponse search(@RequestPayload MySoapEndpointRequest request) {
    throw new SoapFaultException("Service not implemented yet!");
 }

}
```

Any ideas?